# Search query, capital letters

Tags: php, forms, search

Can someone help me with this. The form needs to make no difference between capital letters and normal letters.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (`naam` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`titel` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`druk` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

The charset is latin1_bin

Comment: Extreme SQL Injection Alert

Comment: "the form" and you show us a query?

Comment: Sorry, i changed it;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `UPPER` in mysql.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (UPPER(naam) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%')) OR (UPPER(titel) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%')) OR (UPPER(druk) LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%'))") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Invalid use `LIKE '%".UPPER($query)."%'` or your fixed one `LIKE '%UPPER(".$query.")%'`. Function should be outside of the string `LIKE UPPER('%".$query."%')`.

Comment: Thanks and sorry about that.

Comment: Can to answer this question.. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066980/11065582

Answer (score 1):

That depends of collation that you're using for your field. With default `latin1_general_ci` collation (or similar `_ci`-ended) comparison and string functions will be insensitive to case.

So, you have two options. First - use [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) in your PHP application or [LOWER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lower) in MySQL itself - to convert your search strings to lower case (i.e. make them independent of their original content case). Second - use the corresponding collation for fields containing your data. More information than I've already provided - is in [case sensitivity manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) to Lowercase all your query and then do the search.

Something like this so it will match all.

```
$query=strtolower($query);
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (`naam` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`titel` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`druk` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mb_strtolower()` should be used instead of `strtolower`.

Comment: I don't think they make much of a difference.

Comment: ofc they do, example: `echo strtolower('Š') . mb_strtolower('Š');` will output `Šš`. But yes, it depends on what kind of charset will OP use.

Comment: the charset is latin1_bin

Comment: @Glavić, +1 for the explanation.

Answer (score -3):

convert all into either lowercase or upper case it will work

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product
            WHERE (strtolower(naam) LIKE '%".strtolower($query)."%') OR (strtolower(titel) LIKE '%".strtolower($query)."%') OR (strtolower(druk) LIKE '%".strtolower($query)."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `strtolower` is not a mysql function.