# How to change query?(user type capital or simple letters, filtering)

Tags: dart, flutter

I used this query to search. I used SearchDelegate.

```
 final suggestList = assetArray
        .where((p) => p.contains(query)).toList();
```

my List like this,

```
final assertArray = [
'1001: Rm Standard','500: Rm King','1001: Rm Standard','1001: Rm Twin','1001: Rm Delux']
```

When I search the same letter code is working, but when searching in lowercase, does not filter.

**I need to filter whatever letter typed user needs to filter**

Comment: Convert your p value to lowercase and your query value to lowercase, this way no matter what the user has enter it will work.

Comment: if convert P value to lower, my display values also lower. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

change into this:

```
final suggestList = assetArray
        .where((p) => p.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look updated code:

```
final suggestList = assetArray
        .where((p) => p.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).toList();
```